# Cassandra 2.0.4 fails to count rows with Illegal Capacity: -1

Tags: cassandra

I have a row I cannot run a count against, when I do I get Illegal Capacity: -1

Here's an example of get following a count of the same row:
Connected to:

```
"Newvem" on 127.0.0.1/9160
Welcome to Cassandra CLI version 2.0.4

[default@cwt] count cw_last['320264f0-9191-11e3-a614-22000ac40c04'];
=> (name=AWS/EBS:VolumeIdleTime:ap-southeast-1:VolumeId=vol-45654642, value=, timestamp=1391953862644000, ttl=604800)
=> (name=AWS/EBS:VolumeIdleTime:ap-southeast-1:VolumeId=vol-12312312, value=, timestamp=1391953857233000, ttl=604800)
=> (name=AWS/EBS:VolumeIdleTime:ap-southeast-1:VolumeId=vol-34534534, value=, timestamp=1391953870843000, ttl=604800)
=> (name=AWS/EBS:VolumeIdleTime:ap-southeast-1:VolumeId=vol-45645645, value=, timestamp=1391953857233000, ttl=604800)
=> (name=AWS/EBS:VolumeIdleTime:ap-southeast-1:VolumeId=vol-45645645, value=, timestamp=1391953872974000, ttl=604800)
=> (name=AWS/EBS:VolumeIdleTime:ap-southeast-1:VolumeId=vol-23432423, value=, timestamp=1391953858653000, ttl=604800)
=> (name=AWS/EBS:VolumeIdleTime:ap-southeast-1:VolumeId=vol-45645654, value=, timestamp=1391953875025000, ttl=604800)
=> (name=AWS/EBS:VolumeIdleTime:ap-southeast-1:VolumeId=vol-57563453, value=, timestamp=1391953869352000, ttl=604800)
=> (name=AWS/EBS:VolumeIdleTime:ap-southeast-1:VolumeId=vol-76577676, value=, timestamp=1391953861980000, ttl=604800)
=> (name=AWS/EBS:VolumeIdleTime:ap-southeast-1:VolumeId=vol-12321321, value=, timestamp=1391953866898000, ttl=604800)
=> (name=AWS/EBS:VolumeIdleTime:ap-southeast-1:VolumeId=vol-12365732, value=, timestamp=1391953861980000, ttl=604800)
=> (name=AWS/EBS:VolumeIdleTime:ap-southeast-1:VolumeId=vol-12478564, value=, timestamp=1391953863313000, ttl=604800)
=> (name=AWS/EBS:VolumeIdleTime:ap-southeast-1:VolumeId=vol-12363456, value=, timestamp=1391953862644000, ttl=604800)
=> (name=AWS/EBS:VolumeIdleTime:ap-southeast-1:VolumeId=vol-54623423, value=, timestamp=1391953872974000, ttl=604800)
=> (name=AWS/EBS:VolumeIdleTime:ap-southeast-1:VolumeId=vol-10123122, value=, timestamp=1391953860598000, ttl=604800)
=> (name=AWS/EBS:VolumeIdleTime:ap-southeast-1:VolumeId=vol-11asdsaa, value=, timestamp=1391953864913000, ttl=604800)
=> (name=AWS/EBS:VolumeIdleTime:ap-southeast-1:VolumeId=vol-157ffdfg, value=, timestamp=1391953862644000, ttl=604800)
=> (name=AWS/EBS:VolumeIdleTime:ap-southeast-1:VolumeId=vol-16312332, value=, timestamp=1391953867546000, ttl=604800)
=> (name=AWS/EBS:VolumeIdleTime:ap-southeast-1:VolumeId=vol-16f12435, value=, timestamp=1391953867546000, ttl=604800)
=> (name=AWS/EBS:VolumeIdleTime:ap-southeast-1:VolumeId=vol-11231212, value=, timestamp=1391953858653000, ttl=604800)
...MORE RESULTS, TRUNCATED...
Returned 3072 results.
Elapsed time: 1547 msec(s).
[default@cwt] get cw_last['320264f0-9191-11e3-a614-22000ac40c04'];
Illegal Capacity: -1
InvalidRequestException(why:Illegal Capacity: -1)
    at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Cassandra$get_count_result$get_count_resultStandardScheme.read(Cassandra.java:13038)
    at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Cassandra$get_count_result$get_count_resultStandardScheme.read(Cassandra.java:13016)
    at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Cassandra$get_count_result.read(Cassandra.java:12944)
    at org.apache.thrift.TServiceClient.receiveBase(TServiceClient.java:78)
    at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Cassandra$Client.recv_get_count(Cassandra.java:697)
    at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Cassandra$Client.get_count(Cassandra.java:681)
    at org.apache.cassandra.cli.CliClient.executeCount(CliClient.java:448)
    at org.apache.cassandra.cli.CliClient.executeCLIStatement(CliClient.java:237)
    at org.apache.cassandra.cli.CliMain.processStatementInteractive(CliMain.java:201)
    at org.apache.cassandra.cli.CliMain.main(CliMain.java:331)
[default@cwt]
```

The cf has LCS(LeveledCompactionStrategy) but nothing special other than that.
This error also happens when I write the same data on a different row(so it probably has something to do with the data rather than with a specific server - I have 3 of them)

No deletes are performed on this CF(or on any of my CFs)

Anyone knows why this might happen or how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

This is a know issue that has been resolved in cassandra 2.0.5, take a look at the [CASSANDRA-6555](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-6555) ticket and [CASSANDRA-6684](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-6684)